# Using PHP to Match a Javascript Timestamp

Tags: php, javascript

Alright when I do the code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
document.write((new Date).getTime());
</script>
```

You get the Unix timestamp in miliseconds. I need something that will match this in PHP. I need a variable to be set to that, NOT necessarily printed. The variable needs to be a string OR number without any formatting (decimals, commas, etc).

The numbers don't have to match exactly, but have to be close. I tried doing time()*1000 but it turns it into scientific notation and I couldn't format it out without messing up the string.

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CPqRr/

Comment: Is the additional precision (the last three digits) that important? Can you remove them and move on?

Comment: This will probably help too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1063539/451969

Comment: You can also use `Date.now()` to get an equivalent timestamp as well. Not sure about how compatible it is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need (millisecond) presision, then just divide & Math.floor the javascript's function. So:

```
time();
```

and

```
Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000)
```

should return the same value at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is millisecond time in PHP. To accomplish this you need to use a combination of the [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function and some multiplication.

[`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) when passed `true` as its first parameter will return the current time as the number of seconds since the Unix epoch to the nearest microsecond.

To convert the value into an integer value of the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch you must multiply this value by 1000 and cast to an integer.

So:

```
$milliseconds = (int)(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Comment: Few problems there, `microtime()` returns the number of milliseconds, not seconds. Also, don't forget the `$` sigil.

Comment: @alex: microtime returns seconds when passed true as the parameter. The microseconds are given as the value after the decimal. Take a look at the linked manual page; it was a new addition in PHP 5.

Comment: @MitMaro I shall read more of the documentation before I open my mouth :)

Comment: This code fails on 32-bit builds of PHP as it overflows. suggest use floor(), or from php 6 onwards, (long)().

Answer (score 0):

The javascript

```
getTime() ;
```

method returns the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

A php equivalent is

```
time() * 1000; // not microtime() as I wrongly said earlier.
```

However they wont match as php does not support millisecond precision it seems.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but...getTime() is outputting 1329034097600 and time() is outputting 1329034082. I have both these being generated on the same page close to the same time.

Comment: I don't know if `microtime()` is what the OP is looking for here. Demo: http://codepad.org/5WJrKXzf

Comment: I tried that as well. microtime just came up with:"0.40322000 1329034292" and getTime() gave: 1329034307542

Comment: Doesnt have to be too precise, the problem is that time()*1000 puts it in scientific notation....

I guess I'll just add three zeros as a string instead of making it an integer

Comment: @user1019588 - See my Codepad link in my above comment.