# How to display total number of days between two dates using php

Tags: php, html, date

I want to count the total number of days between two date.

> Note: I am not talking about the difference between two date

I found lots of answer on google and Stack Overflow. I am sharing here

```
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$your_date = strtotime("2018-06-01");
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
echo round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Output is 9

```
$now = strtotime("2018-06-09");
$your_date = strtotime("2018-06-01"); 
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
echo $numberDays= round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Output is 8

```
$dStart = new DateTime('2018-06-01');
$dEnd  = new DateTime('2018-06-09');
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
echo $dDiff->days;
```

Output is 8

```
$date1=date_create("2018-06-01");
$date2=date_create("2018-06-09");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%a");
```

Output is 8

```
$startTimeStamp = strtotime("2018-06-01");
$endTimeStamp = strtotime("2018-06-09");
$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);
$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day
// and you might want to convert to integer
echo $numberDays = intval($numberDays);
```

Output is 8

The correct answer for me is the first one 9 because it displays the total number of days from 1 to 9, not a difference.

I just want to know how to get the count because I don't want to use the time() because it's taking the current date.

For example: If I select the first date 2018-05-01 and my second date in 2018-05-31. So total days is 31, not 30.

Example: 
I am working on a project which is related to the working days and salary. So employee will select the date. for example. I am the employee and in the last month May, I select the date 2018-05-01 and 2018-05-31 so I have to display the total working days.So the according to the date I worked 31 days and using above code in the question I am getting 30 days.

Hope you understand my issue. Would you help me out in this?

Comment: Just add one to the output of your calculations

Comment: @Andreas, In the January month, total days is 31. So You start the work from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-31 so if I check the different, It will display 30 but I worked 31 days in the company. So I need output 31. Hope you understand this.

Comment: Yes, and if you get 30 from the calculation you just add 1 to it and you get 31. Why make it any harder than it needs to be?

Comment: @Andreas, I am working on a project which is related to the working days and salary. So employee will select the date. for example. I am the employee and in the last month May, I select the date 2018-05-01 and 2018-05-31 so I have to display the total working days.

Comment: So the according to the date I worked 31 days and using above code in the question I am getting 30 days. Any more idea in this?

Comment: It will be good for me if share the reason for the downvote. I will improve in the future.

Comment: You are not listening. Quite frankly, if you are building code for salary calculations then just give it up.

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks for the suggestion. If you want to display the total working days in the last month then how can you display it?

Comment: By adding one (+1) to the calculation! Here I will spell it out loud and clear now: https://3v4l.org/9QeoT

Comment: @Andreas, Cool!!. Is it a good thing to do? I mean adding a (+1).  just for my information.

Comment: Oh! you added the +1 information in the second comment. I forgot to check that. Thanks @Andreas

Comment: Finally!! Yes! If you always calculate something to be one day less than you want it to be, then just add one to the calculation. And it's a perfectly fine way of doing it. As long as you are not expecting 30 one time and 31 the next.

Comment: I wrote *Just add one* 48 minutes ago on my first comment too

Comment: @Andreas, yes, I forgot to check that because of lots of notification was coming. Thanks for the help, I will try this.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this-

```
$dateOne = new DateTime("01-01-2018");
$dateTwo = new DateTime("09-06-2018");

echo $diff = $dateTwo->diff($dateOne)->format("%a");
```

**Output-**    159

Comment: Can you explain me more?

Comment: DateTime::diff -- DateTimeImmutable::diff -- DateTimeInterface::diff -- date_diff — Returns the difference between two DateTime objects

Comment: FYI, this will technically output negative days, if you add %r for the sign. If this were a "start" and "end" situation, you'd want to flip it to be:  $dateOne->diff($dateTwo)->format("%a");

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DateTime` class and compare them via `diff()` method. `$date1->diff($date2)`. The output will give you an accurate result of days:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2018-01-01');
$date2 = new DateTime('2018-02-15');

print_r($date1->diff($date2));
```

Output:

```
DateInterval Object 
( 
[y] => 0 
[m] => 1 
[d] => 14 
[h] => 0 
[i] => 0 
[s] => 0 
[f] => 0 
[weekday] => 0 
[weekday_behavior] => 0 
[first_last_day_of] => 0 
[invert] => 0 
[days] => 45 
[special_type] => 0 
[special_amount] => 0 
[have_weekday_relative] => 0 
[have_special_relative] => 0 
)
```

Comment: I need an answer 46, not 45, Because in the January total days is 31 and in fab 15 so 31+15=46

Comment: You can modify the first date, if you need to include the start date as count: `$date1->modify('-1 day');`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

Output : 272 days.

Comment: It will be good for me if you use my date and time which I added to the question for easy, quick and fast to understand

Comment: The function  date_diff(datetime1,datetime2,absolute); returns a DateInterval object on success that represents the difference between the two dates. FALSE on failure

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
  <?php
    $start_date = "2020-12-24";
    $end_date   = "2020-12-31";
    $dateDiff   = strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date);
    $numOfDays  = $dateDiff / 86400;
    echo $numOfDays;
  ?>
```

Output: 7

Answer (score 0):

here i got your solution in first program php  time(); function is dynamically change as per current time in millisecond (In PHP you can simply call time() to get the time passed since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT in seconds) here you are using round function to get rounded value after 12pm it your calculation  will increase more then 8.5 and you get a rounded value which is 9

here brief explanation [Getting unix timestamp in milliseconds in PHP5 and Actionscript3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063513/getting-unix-timestamp-in-milliseconds-in-php5-and-actionscript3)

in rest of program you are taking static time or custom time which are not effected by system time

```
    $now = time(); // or your date as well
    $your_date = strtotime("2018-06-01");
    $datediff = $now - $your_date;
    echo round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

try above program before 12pm maybe you got your answer

Comment: In the January month, total days is 31. So You start the work from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-31 so if I check the different, It will display 30 but I worked 31 days in the company. So I need output 31.

Comment: I have to get the value from the user not from the time() function. Time() will dislay the current date.

Comment: Not only day it is int form of date and time

Answer (score 0):

First compile and print `$now` and write down out put after some minutes 2nd time compile and print `$now` you will ge a difference